# "Some packages were found but are not compatible updates. " error on android

Tags: android

I get this error when trying to get new packages on the SDK manager:

"Some packages were found but are not compatible updates."

I've had a look around and the only thing I can find is to do with an older version of java, but I have the latest version, java 6 update 20.

So, does anyone have any ideas of what I can do?

I'm using Win 7 32.

Comment: Try checking if SDK manager is using that java version.

Comment: I've only got one version of java installed, so as far as I can tell it's fine. I also installed WinXP mode fresh anyways with the same version, and got the same problem.

Either way, I managed to get it to run eventually so it's all good (still get that error but hey ho).